# Departure on last day of Schengen Visa validity

Tags: schengen, visa-expiration

I will be soon going to Netherlands from India. My schengen visa validity expires on 30th July and I will be leaving on the same date as well and reach India on 31st July. Will there be any problem that my schengen visa is expired during the return journey?

Answer (score 6):

No, no problem since you will be leaving on the 30th. The fact that you arrive in India on 31st isn't an issue. While you are flying, you aren't considered as being into the Schengen area anymore.

The only risk you are taking here is if there is a delay in the flight. Then your visa will expire before you'll be leaving.

Comment: If the flight is delayed there should be no problem as the circumstances are beyond the traveler's control. If she misses the flight of her own accord, however, that would be a different story.

Answer (score 2):

no problem even you exit Schengen area last date of your visa,
the only concern is you should not exceed no of days allowed in your Schenegn 
visa.For instance visa validity is 1 month and duration of stay allowed in Schengen visa 15 days, otherwise would be tough to get next Schengen visa again.

Comment: This is an excellent point, but it could be taken to mean that a 1-month visa *necessarily* has a 15-day duration of stay.  In fact, the duration of stay is given explicitly on each visa, and isn't necessarily half the number of days of validity.

Comment: here for example is an image of a 15-day visa with 15 days validity and 15 days duration of stay: https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAJxAAAAJGI0YzA4ZDBmLTI2MDAtNGFmOS04YzdiLTAxMzQyMzA1ZTcwYw.jpg

Comment: here is an example of limited duration of stay. i hope it will clear everything now http://calabazilla.com/2012/10/26/how-to-apply-for-a-schengen-visa-at-the-embassy-of-italy-in-manila/